# Angular: Atribuição de valor a variável

Tags: angular, typescript, front-end, component

Tenho um método que chama um serviço de uma API e armazena o resultado dele em uma variável, mas esse resultado não está sendo atribuido a variável que eu preciso.

```
atribuirImagem(): void {
    this.imagemService.enviarArquivo(this.arquivoSelecionado)
      .subscribe(
        image => {
         //Atribuindo valor
          this.usuario.imagem = image;
        });
  }
```

Tenho outro método para chamar um serviço que envia um usuário `POST` pela API. Mas nesse usuário que eu passo como parâmetro não chega a variável que eu atribui no outro método.

```
cadastrarUsuario(): void {
    this.ativarSpinner = true;

if(this.arquivoSelecionado != null){
  this.atribuirImagem();
}

this.usuarioService.cadastrarNovoUsuario(this.usuario)
  .subscribe(
    ok => {},
    err => {
      this.mensagemValidacao = err.error;
    });

this.ativarSpinner = false;
```

}

O usuário que está sendo passado como parâmetro **não tem o valor** que foi atribuído no outro método. Qual o problema nesse caso?

Comment: image => { console.log(image)} qual o valor printado?

Comment: Suponho que como o método é assincrono, você só vai conseguir o que deseja se você colocar o trecho de cadastrarNovoUsuario dentro do image => {

Comment: @veroneseComS o valor printado é o nome da imagem mesmo.

Comment: Provavelmente seu problema será resolvido se você passar o conteudo de cadastrarNovoUsuario pra dentro do seu subscribe

Comment: @veroneseComS no caso image => { metodo(). Seria isso?

Comment: image => { this.usuarioService.cadastrarNovoUsuario...

Comment: @veroneseComS Fiz dessa forma, deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O **Angular** usa `observables` ​​como uma interface para lidar com uma variedade de operações **assíncronas** comuns e é por isto que você não consegue utilizar o valor atribuído nesta variável para fora do `subscribe`.

Você possui diversas outras maneiras para utilizar o valor do `subscribe`, mas usar uma variável auxiliar de fora para pegar o valor dentro do `subscribe` e utiliza-lá fora você não irá conseguir, então você pode:

- **1)** Inserir todo o código necessário dentro do `subscribe`;
- **2)** Criar uma função que retorna um `Observable` e dar `subscribe` utilizando esta função;
- **3)** Deixar a programação reativa a eventos e utilizar o `.toPromise()` e retornar um `Promise<>` em um método;

Answer (score 0):

Cara tenta dessa forma. Qualquer duvida cola no stackblitz que eu te ajudo.

```js
async atribuirImagem(): void {
    this.imagemService.enviarArquivo(this.arquivoSelecionado)
      .subscribe(
        image => {
         //Atribuindo valor
          this.usuario.imagem = image;
         await this.efetivaCadastro(this.usuario);
        });
  }


async cadastrarUsuario(): void {
    this.ativarSpinner = true;

if(this.arquivoSelecionado != null){
  await this.atribuirImagem();
}
this.ativarSpinner = false;
}


async efetivaCadastro(user): void {
this.usuarioService.cadastrarNovoUsuario(user)
  .subscribe(
    ok => {console.log(ok)},
    err => {
      this.mensagemValidacao = err.error;
    });
}
```